# How to use jQuery / CSS to swap out the contents of a DIV onmouseover on list items?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a list of links, followed by a DIV, like this:

```
<div class="masthead screen">

<ul class="mast screen">
<li><a href="#">Relacionarse<br />con Efectividad</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Productividad<br />Personal</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Confianza</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vivir la Vida<br />Plenamente</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Rompimientos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hacer una<br />Diferencia</a></li>                  
</ul>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>DEFAULT TEXT una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK ONE en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK TWO en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK THREE en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK FOUR en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK FIVE en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

<div class="mast-text screen"><p>LINK SIX en una era de rompimientos–una era de avances sin precedentes que han mejorado ampliamente la calidad de nuestras vidas</p>
<p><span class="size-16"><strong>El Foro Landmark</strong></span><br />es ese tipo de rompimiento. Es un rompimiento en lo que es posible para las personas</p>
</div>

</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var $container = $(".masthead"),
        $testimonials = $(".mast-text", $container).hide();

    $(".mast li", $container).hover(function() {
        $testimonials.eq( $(this).addClass("active").index() ).show();
    }, function() {
        $testimonials.eq( $(this).removeClass("active").index() ).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

The on hover swaps work, but I don't know how to display default content for when hover is not engaged.

I need to have the contents of the first `.mast-text` DIV to be the default if nothing is hovered over.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Where are you struggling?

Comment: Did you try something ? We could do it but if you're not trying and seeing a problem, it looks just like work delegation.

Comment: See edit for what I am currently trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    // store default content
    var def = $('#swap').html();

    $('a').hover(function(){
        $('#swap').html($($(this).attr('href')).html());
    }, function(){
        $('#swap').html(def);
    });
});
```

Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycyfn/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').hover(function(){
   var ind=$(this).index();
   $('#swap').html($('.swaps').eq(ind).html());
},function(){
   $('#swap').html('DEFAULT CONTENT FOR WHEN NOTHING TRIGGERED');
 });
```

give swap divs class="swaps"